Inconsistency between Horizons data retrieved via Astroquery and Horizons web interface
I am attempting to obtain the x, y, z coordinates of the Sun-asteroid vector using Horizons.
The code I wrote is:
jd_tdb = Time(2457171.6650230, format='jd', scale='utc').tdb.value
obj_sun = Horizons(id=21, location='500@10',
        epochs=jd_tdb, id_type='smallbody')
vec_sun = obj_sun.vectors()

The obtained values are:

However, the Horizons website and/or the 'raw_response' in Astroquery provide:

So, there is a small difference (but important for astrometric purposes) between the outputs.

Does anyone have insight into the issue?
Thank you.
